# Integers with a given digit sum

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning

My aim is to generate a list of integers less than a given value $r$ with their digit sum equal to $s$.

My code given below works fine but it is slow. I would like to see efficient versions.

```
f[r_,s_]:=Select[Range[r], Total[IntegerDigits[#]] == s &]
```

Comment: What is $s$ representing in your code? Is that $k$? Looks like it, but checking...

Comment: @MikeY Thanks for pointing that out. I will update the question.

Answer (score 7):

We can work backwards so to speak:

```
f[r_, s_] := Union[Select[
  FromDigits /@ Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[s, Ceiling[Log10[r]], Range[0, 9]], 
  LessThan[r]
]]
```

Example:

```
f[1000, 6]
```

> ```
> {6, 15, 24, 33, 42, 51, 60, 105, 114, 123, 132, 141, 150, 204, 213, 222, 231, 240, 303, 312, 321, 330, 402, 411, 420, 501, 510, 600}
> ```

```
Total[IntegerDigits[f[1000, 6]], {2}]
```

> ```
> {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
> ```

Larger example:

```
vals = f[10^12, 100]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.069749, Null}
> ```

```
Length[vals]
```

> ```
> 75582
> ```

Verify:

```
Total[IntegerDigits[vals], {2}] // Union
```

> ```
> {100}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But, I noticed that for f[1000,1] returns me only {1}, instead of {1,10,100}.

Comment: @Expikx Documentation details for `IntegerPartitions` shows it defaults to using numbers > 0. Change his `Range[9]` to `Range[0,9]` and it will include 10 and 100 in the results for `f[1000,1]`. Perhaps that will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @Bill thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my solution.

Comment: @Bill That fixed it. Thanks.